# Getting 403 Forbidden while posting message to google+ using nodejs

Tags: node.js, request

I'm actually implementing Social sharing in my project, so i am doing google+ sharing. While posting message to Google+ using nodejs,I'm getting 403 forbidden error  do i need to configure anything on google+ account so that posted message is seen at google+

```
 var params = {         "object": {
                        "originalContent": "hello"
                    },
                    "access": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "mycircle"
                    }
                ],
                        "domainRestricted": true
                    }
                };
                var headers = {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + google_access_token
                };

                    request.post(shareApiUrl, {
                        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/{{userid}}/activities',
                        headers: headers,
                        body: params,
                        json: true

                    }, function (err, response, body) {
                     console.log(body)
    )}
Error Description:
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden",
                "message": "Forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Forbidden"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Posting a feed/or message we should have Google Apps account, but it is impossible with regular GMail account, or your Apps admin hasn't enabled Google+ for the Apps domain.